# Is there a python function that splits lines when trying to send information to a mysql database?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am doing a project in which I have to send information from a text
    document into a local mysql database server.  I have managed to split the
    list of information that is displayed like this :

```
11/04/19,17:04,12.0,79,8.5,1.0,1.7,279
11/04/19,17:05,12.0,79,8.5,1.0,1.7,278
```

But spliting this gives me the first items of both lines.
    I am looking for a way to separate each individual item from each line, 
    to then sent it into my database.

I have tried text.Split( but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import mysql.connector

sql = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='sdf',
    db="weather"
    )
cursor = sql.cursor()

f = open("C:\Cumulus\data\Apr19log.txt","r")

while True:
    s = f.readline()
    list=[]
    if (s != ""):
       #can i add a line split here?
       t=s.split(',')
       for item in t:
            list.append(item)
       print(list[5])
```

The output is:

> 0.1
>
> 0.1

How do I separate each item from each line?

Comment: You're reading the file line-by-line already. What do you mean by split line again?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather coding as bellow:

```
import mysql.connector
from pathlib import Path

sql = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost", user="root", password="sdf", db="weather"
)
cursor = sql.cursor()

fname = "C:\Cumulus\data\Apr19log.txt"
datas = [line.split(',') for line in Path(fname).read_text().splitlines()]
print(datas)
```